# Update an empty table with an INNER JOIN UPDATE statement based on another filled table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join

IMPORTANT:
I'm really a rookie in using MYSQL.

I have to table, and I'm trying to use an update statement instead of using an insert statement to update a table, base on another table on a inner join query.

My first table looks like the following:

exp_credit_tracker_designation

```
id association_id designation_name
```

is base on the other table:

exp_credit_tracker_assoc:

```
id, credit_type, association_name, address, city, province, postal_code, country, cycle_type, cycle_begin, cycle_months

'1', '2', 'Association', '14 bloor street', 'Toronto', 'ON', 'M5S 2E5', 'US', '2', '1526356800', '7'
'2', '2', 'designation', '40 Willcocks St', 'Ottawa', 'BC', 'M5S 2E5', 'CA', '1', '1526356800', '3'
'3', '2', 'credit types', '85 St George St', 'Toronto', 'AL', 'M5S 2E5', 'US', '2', '1540008000', '3'
'4', '1', 'association', '46 muriel ave', 'St. John', 'NB', 'M5M 2L2', 'US', '1', '1526356800', '4'
'5', '1', 'designation', '10 king street', 'Toronto', 'ON', 'M5S 2E5', 'CA', '2', '1526529600', '9'
```

Now, as you can notice, the first table doesn't have any value at the moment and my hope is to automatically update my table with a INNER JOIN statement base on my update. Something in the line of:

```
UPDATE exp_credit_tracker_designation
INNER JOIN exp_credit_tracker_assoc ON exp_credit_tracker_designation.assocaition_id = exp_credit_tracker_assoc.id
SET exp_credit_tracker_assoc.id = exp_credit_tracker_designation.assocaition_id
```

For me it could be the faster way to populate my brand new table and interact with them.

I'm not sure if it is possible or even if it makes sense.

I will be waiting for a good suggestion about the approach to follow in those cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you want to update the `exp_credit_tracker_designation` table with data from another table, even though `exp_credit_tracker_designation` doesn't have any data in it already, This is not possible with an update statement

Update statements change existing data and since there is no data there already, there is nothing to update, at least thats how I interpret your question.

You will have to use an insert statement to input that data from one table to another if the other has no data already. This is quite simple to accomplish
you can do a statement like this:

```
insert into table1 (column1, column2, column3)
select column1, column2, column3 from table2
```

Since you say you are rather new to MySQL you may notice that I did not use the traditional syntax of

```
Insert into foo (bar, biz, bad)
values (X, Y, Z)
```

this is because you are pulling data from another table.